# Можно ли сортировать JSON в обратном порядке?

Tags: php, json

Есть такой [json](http://w-0rld.ru/json/news), в обычном порядке его удобно использовать для отображения одной новости, а в порядке "по убыванию", его удобно использовать для отображения всех новостей (сначала новые, ниже старые).

Как можно это сделать?

```
$json = json_decode($output);
$json_main = $json->News;
if ($_GET['action'] == 'news')
{
$content .= '<div class="News">';
foreach ($json_main as $item)
{
$content.= '<div class="New"><div class="NewsTitle"><a href="/new/'.$item->ID.'" onclick="getNewsOne('.$item->ID.');">'.$item->Title.'</a></div><div class="NewsContent">'.$item->ShortContent.'</div></div>';
}
$content .= '</div>';
Show($content,'Новости');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду после операции `$json_main = $json->News;` в $json_main будет массив, поэтому к нему можно применить функцию `array_reverse`.

Т.е если вам нужно отсортировать массив в обратном порядке вы просто делаете так

```
$sorted = array_reverse($json->News);
```